# Is there any difference with "navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:" between ios4 and ios5?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, ios5

I create a UINavigationController, and add a UINavigationControllerDelegate instance methods
"navigationController:didShowViewContrlooer:animated".
Then I push a UIViewController A to UINavigationController, and in the method "viewDidLoad" of A, I push an another UIViewController B to UINavigationController.

Now is the question:

1. In iOS4, when I push A, the method "navigationController:didShowViewContrlooer:animated" will be called for A and B.
2. In iOS5, when I push A, the method "navigationController:didShowViewContrlooer:animated" will only be called for B.

So, anybody can help me, Is there any difference with "navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:" between ios4 and ios5?

Comment: There are several changes to how navigation controllers work between iOS 4 and iOS 5.  Can't answer your specific question, though.

Comment: But the "UINavigationControllerDelegate Protocol Reference" of ios4 and ios5 are the same, it's really strange.@HotLicks

Comment: Yeah, Apple made a lot of of incompatible changes between 4 and 5.  I'm guessing that at least 50% of apps are broken, and virtually all the more complex ones.